# Refresh data from DB(EF, MVVM)

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm

Faced with such a situation. The program is running. I change the data in the table wrk_Device_Value NOT from the program. Next, run the method for filling the collection, which contains the following code. Querying the database is done (look through Profiler), but the data collection remain the old data.

What could be wrong?

```
            ValuesList = new ObservableCollection<wrk_Device_Value>
            (_dataContext.wrk_Device_Value.Where(d => d.ID_Device == device.ID_Device).ToList());
```

MainWindow:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Messenger.Default.Register<string>("ShowMainWindow", p => { });

        Messenger.Default.Register<DEVICE>(this, "ShowDialogWindow", p =>
        {
            var dlg = new EditPropertyValuesWindow();
            dlg.Owner = this;
            dlg.DataContext = DataContext;
            dlg.ShowDialog();
        }
        );
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = _mainViewModel;
    }
}
```

MainViewModel:

```
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDisposable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private AVTEntities _dataContext;
    public ObservableCollection<spr_TypeDevice> TypesOfDevice { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this._dataContext = new AVTEntities();

        TypesOfDevice = new ObservableCollection<spr_TypeDevice>
            (_dataContext.spr_TypeDevice.OrderBy(a=>a.Name_TypeDevice)); 
        Save = new RelayCommand (SaveAllChanges);
    }


    private DEVICE _selectedDevice;
    public DEVICE SelectedDevice
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedDevice;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedDevice = value;
            LoadHistory();
        } 
    }

    private List<wrk_Device_ValueLog> _historyList;
    public List<wrk_Device_ValueLog> HistoryList
    {
        get { return _historyList; }
        set
        {
            _historyList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<wrk_Device_Value> _valuesList;
    public ObservableCollection<wrk_Device_Value> ValuesList
    {
        get { return _valuesList; }
        set
        {
            if (_valuesList == value) return;
            _valuesList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ValuesList");
            //NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void LoadValues()
    {
        DEVICE device = this.SelectedDevice;
        if (device == null) return;

        ValuesList = new ObservableCollection<wrk_Device_Value>
            (_dataContext.wrk_Device_Value.Where(d => d.ID_Device == device.ID_Device).ToList());

    }
```

Comment: please provide more detail about.

When is your data context is initiated ?

Comment: @Eldho  I added the code. Data context is initiated in constructor of MainViewModel. I use one ViewModel for two Views(Parent and Child). This can be problem?

Comment: is  RaisePropertyChanged("ValuesList"); hit while debugging  ValuesList = new ObservableCollection<wrk_Device_Value>
            (_dataContext.wrk_Device_Value.Where(d => d.ID_Device == device.ID_Device).ToList()); ?

Comment: @blindmeis I tried RaisePropertyChanged("ValuesList"). While debugging collection remain old data.

Comment: Don't do this.  Remove old values from the collection and add new ones to it.  Or don't use an ObservableCollection *at all*.  Simply expose an IEnumerable<T> property and make it INPC.

Comment: @Eldho I'm a little headway. If i change the data in one column - in the collection are the old data, but when i delete row in the table, data collection updated. Is something wrong with my model class?

Comment: @Alex Is you ef context aware of the change ? if its aware of the change implement `RaisePropertyChanged()` in the class you are binding. Please use a `Model object` to `bind the view model` exposing the EF tables directly to the View-model are not a good practice. Add `Model` object implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in that `class` use the `ObservableCollection<yourModel> ValuesList` in your viewmodel.

Comment: As i remember `ObservableCollection` wont update when a `column` is updated. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha.

Use `ObservableCollection` in wpf if you are binding something to view.

Comment: @Eldho Where can i look if context aware of the change?

Comment: @Alex try a break point where you load the values from database. here its `LoadValues()` when assigning to `ValuesList` make sure the collection contains your values

Comment: @Eldho Problem in _dataContext.wrk_Device_Value. It returns old value.

Comment: try initiating the `datacontext` before you fetching the data. Mostly because the ef is not aware of the changes in the data store.